# Null Reference Exception (C#)

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to load the contents of a text file into a RichTextBox control. The code I'm using is:

```
notesTextbox.LoadFile(notesFilePath);
```

Now each time I run it I get a null reference exception. I'm sure the solution is simple, I've just hit a mental block. Can anyone offer any assistance? Thanks.

Comment: Use the debugger. Look at the duplicate, it contains a lot of useful informations.

Comment: Are you sure notesTextBox and notesFilePath are not null ?

Comment: Added some breakpoints and found that the Textbox was null, I probably should've done that before asking but thank you for your help anyway. I've fixed it now.